# Using and Rather than Implies

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I am trying to understand the difference between and $\wedge$ and $\rightarrow$. Consider
$$x=y\Longleftrightarrow \forall z(z\in x \ \rightarrow z \in y)$$

However, I think we can use and notation rather than implies
$$x=y\Longleftrightarrow \forall z(z\in x \ \wedge \ z \in y)$$

Can you explain briefly we we should use implies notation there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deciding between logical AND (conjunction) and Conditional statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2636633/deciding-between-logical-and-conjunction-and-conditional-statement)

Comment: The first formula above is the def of $\subseteq$.

Answer (score 3):

In English, the first is read as "for all $z$, $z$ being in $x$ implies that $z$ is in $y$". This means that everything in $x$ is also in $y$.

This second is read as "for all $z$, $z$ is in $x$ and $z$ is in $y$". This means that both $x$ and $y$ contain **everything**.

It is worth noting that neither of the two statements above are equivalent to $x=y$, so there is no *reason* to use $\implies$ instead of $\land$ in this case; they just mean different things.